# best way to install node js for C+++ add-on development purpose

Tags: c++, node.js, ubuntu, gcc

1. I install node.js since I heard that we should prefer apt-get installation to native installation from source since it is easy to update or remove. Is it true?
2. What's the right way to determine the correct gcc version to develop node.js C++ addon if we install node.js using apt-get?

   I installed the node.js using apt-get (PPA: [https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/node.js/+packages](https://launchpad.net/%7Echris-lea/+archive/node.js/+packages)) on Ubuntu 12.04. For the C++ development, the gcc(g++) version of node.js and add-on should match to make sure the C++ symbols consistent, right?

Thanks.

Comment: There is a package `nan`  that helps you with the native C++ addon development, https://www.npmjs.com/package/nan

Answer (score 1):

Use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to install from source:

```
nvm install [-s] <version>
```

and Node.js source code will be placed in '$NVM_DIR/src'.

Then use [node-gyp](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp) to configure the environment and build your addon.

```
cd /path/to/your/node/addon/binding.gyp/file/
node-gyp configure
node-gyp build
```

It is practical, you don't need root permissions and will be compiled in the same environment.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's good to know nvm which works well to install the latest node.

One quick question about apt-get. If we use apt-get to install node. Internally, it also does "download source->compile using gcc on the computer->copy files to install", right? That means even if I use apt-get to install node and I write add-on on the same machine, they definitely use the same gcc compiler so I don't need to worry about the C++ version issue.

Thank you very much.

Comment: =)
I don't know how apt-get installs node. I usually compile node from source using `nvm install [-s] <version>`, so it will be the same c++ version I use in my addons.